# Wordpress, Bootstrap 4

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

Что это?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

```
at bootstrap.min.js?ver=20151215:6
at bootstrap.min.js?ver=20151215:6
at bootstrap.min.js?ver=20151215:6
at bootstrap.min.js?ver=20151215:6
```

Comment: Ну это js ошибка.

Comment: Скорее всего зависимости неправильные